# Android Set notification to specific time using service

Tags: java, android

I am using services to make notifications. But the problem I have right now is that the notifications happens at 11:00 AM & PM although I want the notification only happen at 11:00 AM.

This method below is how I set the time. And I wonder how does my service class know what time is set when I set the time on a different class. And this method is not even called from my service class.

```
private void setReminder(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
    String time = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    SavingData.setReminder(time, true);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, myID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Do you want the notification to be sent everyday?

Comment: Yes everyday at specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways I have used to notify the user on a daily basis:

```
Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11); //24-hour format 
firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();

if(intendedTime >= currentTime) 
{
    //this will set the alarm for current day if time is below 11 am
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
else {
    //this will set the alarm for the next day
    firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime , 
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will set an alarm at 11.am

```
PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentService2, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                        int INTERVAL_DAY1 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                        Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
                        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
                        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
                        calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                        long triggerMillis = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();

     alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerMillis,
                                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent2);
```